# Finding the asymptotic distribution of $\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Let $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be a random sample from a population distribution with $E(X_i)=\mu $ and $Var(X_i) =\sigma^2$ for all $i$ find the asymptotic distribution of $T= \frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ ? .

In order to define the asymptotic distribution of $T$ I have used two ways but I got different results .There is some basics I do not know . Here are my attempts  .

**The first way :**

$$ \sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \mu ) = $$
$$ \sqrt{n}(\frac{n}{n+k}\bar{X_{n}} - \mu ) = $$
$$ \sqrt{n}(\frac{n}{n+k}\bar{X_{n}} + \bar{X_{n}} - \bar{X_{n}} - \mu ) = $$
$$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X_{n}}- \mu +\frac{n}{n+k}\bar{X_{n}}  - \bar{X_{n}})  = $$
$$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X_{n}}- \mu - \frac{k}{n+k}\bar{X_{n}} )  = $$
$$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X_{n}}- \mu ) - \frac{\sqrt{n}k}{n+k}\bar{X_{n}}   = $$

By Lindberg-Levy CLT :
$$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X_{n}}- \mu ) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,\sigma^2)$$

And we know that $\bar{X_{n}}$ is a consistent estimator for $\mu$ that means 
$$\bar{X_{n}} \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \mu $$
And the term $\frac{\sqrt{n}k}{n+k} \rightarrow o$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ .Then by Slutsky theorem : 
$$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X_{n}}- \mu ) - \frac{\sqrt{n}k}{n+k}\bar{X_{n}}   =  $$
$$ \sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \mu ) = $$
$$ \sqrt{n}(T - \mu ) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,\sigma^2) $$
**$$T \overset{a}{\sim}N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$$**

**The second way :**
I have tried to find the asymptotic distribution of $T$ like the way by which we can find the asymptotic distribution of $\bar{X_{n}}$ i.e as a linear combination of normal R.V i.e

By Lindberg-Levy CLT :
$$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X_{n}}- \mu ) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,\sigma^2)$$
Let $ Z_n = \sqrt{n}(\bar{X_{n}}- \mu ) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,\sigma^2)$ then $\bar{X_{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \mu $ then $\bar{X_{n}} \overset{a}{\sim}N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$

Now I did the same for $T$ : 
$$ Z_n = \sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i- \mu )$$
$$ Z_n = \frac{n+ k}{n + k}\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i- \mu )=$$
$$ Z_n = \frac{n+ k}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{1}{n+ k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i- \frac{n}{n+ k}\mu )=$$

$$ Z_n = \frac{n+ k}{\sqrt{n}}(T- \frac{n}{n+ k}\mu )=$$ 
Then
$$T=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{ n+ k}Z_n + \frac{n}{ n+ k}\mu $$
Then as a linear combination of normal R.V 
 $$T \overset{a}{\sim}N(\frac{n}{ n+ k} \mu,\frac{n}{ (n+ k)^2}\sigma^2)$$

Can someone tell me please where I am wrong , why I got different results ?

Comment: I don't see what's "wrong" with the second method, since you're taking the limit as $n$ gets large, which makes the $k$ immaterial. In other words $n/(n+k)\approx 1$ and $n+k \approx n$.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks , but the question is now what is the variance of the asymptotic distribution of $T$ ?

Comment: According to your result, it's $\sigma^2/n$ asymptotically.

Comment: @AlexR. So we can say that $$T \overset{a}{\sim}N(\frac{n}{ n+ k} \mu,\frac{n}{ (n+ k)^2}\sigma^2)$$ and as $n$ goes large $$T \overset{a}{\sim}N(\mu,\frac{1}{n}\sigma^2)$$ is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.